# How to pass number through performSelector?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have to pass number (int) to my next method and I amd trying with next code but with no success:

```
int myNumber = 45;
[self performSelector:@selector(startNewThing) withObject:myNumber afterDelay:0.5f];
```

How can I pass number through performSelector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the changes I'd make to your snippet:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:45];
[self performSelector:@selector(startNewThing:) withObject:myNumber afterDelay:0.5f];
```

Note that I placed a colon after `-startNewThing`. That is so the method can accept `myNumber` as an argument. (This is assuming that -startNewThing: really does take an argument.) And since we've changed `myNumber` from a scalar to an object, you'd need to make the appropriate changes to `-startNewThing:`.

Comment: Or, instead of changing the definition of myNumber, just pass @(myNumber) to the withObject parameter. This uses the new NSNumber literal syntax.

Comment: Great, it works. I read on some forums that if you send through anything else but not object your app will crash. So I'm asking is this safe to use (your code)?

Comment: Can you really use @(integer) instead of NSNumber here? I never heard of that.

Comment: @(integer) is just shorthand for making an NSNumber

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to use an NSNumber.

NSNumber *myInt = [NSNumber numberWithInt:myNumber];

then pass that in and when you receive it in the selector:

NSInteger newInteger = [myNumber integerValue];

What is important to understand is that you are using an NSNumber to turn a primitive into an object. I hope that helps.

Comment: I get this error with your code: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5f * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self startNewThing:100];
});
```